# Car hotter in winter

Tags: situation, seasonal

Every day I park my car in the same spot, which has not had any alterations done in years, nor has the surrounding area changed. No new trees, building, etc. I park my car in the same fashion each time, facing the same direction, and don't use a windscreen sunshield nor car cover. The windows are always closed. Nobody touches the vehicle or the surroundings during the day. I live in Beersheba, Israel, about 33 degrees north of the equator. The only changes to the situation in summer and winter are naturally-occurring.

In summer, when I get to the car at the end of the day the car is cool and comfortable. In winter, when I get to the car it is hot and needs to be aired. **WHY?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suspect that it's due to the angle of the sun in the different seasons. The car is probably in the shade during the summer, but in winter, when the sun is at a lower angle in the sky, it shines directly into the car, heating it up.

Comment: I was hoping that this would take longer than half an hour for someone to figure out! Nice work!

Answer (score 10):

A guess:

> Your car usually stands under a simple roof. Maybe theres also a wall to the west.

Explanation:

> In the summer the sun shines almost directly from the top onto your car, but because of the roof the light won't reach. Depending on what time your day "ends" (i would guess you mean your workday) the extra wall to the west will block the sun during evening.
>
>  During winter the sun will shine from a much lower angle in the south of your car and reach beneath the roof.

Comment: That's it!‎‎‎‎‎‎

Answer (score 5):

You have a remote starter, and since you leave the windows closed you start the car about 15 minutes before using it.  In the winter you have the heater on, in the summer you have the air conditioning on, so remote starting the car makes it cool or toasty depending on how you've adjusted the climate controls each day.

Comment: This is the most out-of-the box answer that I've seen yet!

Answer (score 3):

It could also be due to less leaves on trees and so the sun is directly on it but that answer above would be the best answer. Of course speaking outside of physical temperature, your car may seem warmer in the Winter due to it already being cold outside so your going into the warm.

Comment: That is a rather creative thought. Nice!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps trees dropping their leaves?

Answer (score 2):

The car is not hotter.. you are just wearing your winter clothes in the car, so you are hotter. You aren't airing the hot air out, you are letting the cool air in because your body is overheating. Take off your winter clothes when you get in the car. In the summer you do not wear winter clothes, so it won't be so hot.

Comment: That certainly is a new angle to look at it!